# Is there any API to claim hostkey for zoom meeting?

Tags: zoom-sdk

I am writing a sample app to integrate zoom meeting into web application.
I have gone through the below links
https://zoom.github.io/sample-app-web/ZoomMtg.html and
https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api
I will have a button to start a scheduled meeting as a host. Do I have an option to get that host key programmatically and start the meeting as a host?

Comment: What does their documentation say? https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/build/meetings/start

Answer (score 0):

Thanks blurfus. Yes, I missed out on this earlier. Setting role to 1 in config that I send makes me a host. I dont need the hostkey in this case. I need to test it out.